# Advice for combining right-click context menu actions in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, batch, macros

For windows 10 is there a method to combine context menu actions into one click. 
In particular, I'm after a method that will allow multiple anti-virus and anti-malware programs to scan a single file, with a single click. Because it's inconvenient to select each individual program to scan one file.

As always any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although its not exactly what you asked for, I think I have an alternate solution for you.

VirusTotal is a subsidiary of Google and has an [app that integrates into the Windows Explorer context menu](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/desktop-applications/virustotal-uploader).  This will send a file (up to 5 at once) to be scanned by 54 different virus scanners and give you the results.

I find this program to be extremely useful when downloading a new application installer from an unknown source.

---

**Edit:**

It is *probable* you can create a single context menu entry to combine multiple context menu actions.  The problem lies with how each application handles the context menu action.  You *could* figure out how each one works and then create a custom context menu entry.

However, I think I have a better solution.  You can use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to execute multiple context menu actions in a script.  I do not think it would be to difficult to create a script that opens the context menu and then triggers multiple context menu actions, or even use the arrow keys to cycle through the menu to execute context menu actions.

Comment: Virustotal is an excellent website and is one of the context menu scanners I'd planned to integrate.

Comment: @JacobWoodruff I believe I do have a solution, if you feel you can write a simple script.  I added the idea to my answer.  An AHK script should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by writing a vbscript that invokes other context menu actions or verbs registered for the file type you're right-clicking on. The methods that can be used are [InvokeVerb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787816(VS.85).aspx) or [DoIt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774170(VS.85).aspx)

If you can post the exact menu options (caption) with the accelerator keys, a script can be written for that, which can be incorporated to the right-click menu.